# User permissions custom cms

Tags: php, mysql

looking for some advice on my current setup and if there is a better approach (this is my first attempt at building an app like this) but I am at a point where I need user roles, only two so user and admin.

I have a users table and a groups table and also a join table which takes the ID from the users table and the Id from the groups table and I can allocate which group the user belongs too.

I am wanting to set a way to do a couple of things, prevent 'users' accessing the admin area by typing in the url /admin/index.php and also show a link on the index page if they are an admin and not see it it if they are a normal user.

Here is my code to demonstrate that I can show the users role title but struggling at this point:

```
<?php
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
    try{
        $results = $dbh->query("SELECT *
                                FROM groups
                                INNER JOIN user_group_link_table
                                ON groups.id = user_group_link_table.group_id
                                WHERE user_group_link_table.user_id = $user");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$group = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($group as $groups){  

echo 

      $groups["name"]
      // show a link to admins that user do not see?
    ;}
?>
```

I am wondering if my approach is totally wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
<?
include('session.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
if(!ini_get('date.timezone'))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
// This could be an include file for all admin pages
$isAdmin = false;
foreach($group as $groups){
    if($groups['name'] === 'admin'){
        $isAdmin = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$isAdmin){
    header('Location: index.php'); // or some other arbitrary location
    die();
}
?>
```

And I get this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: group in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboardr v3.2.3/admin/header.php on line 12

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboardr v3.2.3/admin/header.php on line 12

Comment: You've headed one of the many right ways. Just stick with it for now and see if you hit any snags. If you do really need just two roles though, you might have overdone it a little bit. Don't fall into the habit of using `SELECT *`; instead, specify what fields you're really going to need. It might save you a bit of hassle in the future.

Comment: I am pleased about that - I guess the issue I have is blocking none admin users getting into the /admin dir im not sure how to approach that?

Comment: I would store thier groups in the session when they log in. Then you can create a function like `isAdmin()` and and return a boolean if they are authenticated and are in the admin group. Then its just a matter of display certain things or redirecting based on that check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wanting to set a way to do a couple of things, prevent 'users' accessing the admin area by typing in the url /admin/index.php and also show a link on the index page if they are an admin and not see it it if they are a normal user.

I'll give you a solution that'll work in your current setup; It's not *the* way to go, but i'll get the job done for now. If you're worried about the user being in a specific role, you're better off specifying that role in your query rather than iterating through all their potential roles.

```php
// This could be an include file for all admin pages
$isAdmin = false;
foreach($group as $groups){
    if($groups['name'] === 'admin'){
        $isAdmin = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$isAdmin){
    header('Location: index.php'); // or some other arbitrary location
    die;
}
```

You'll want to place this at the top of the page, before you spit out any kind of HTML.

Comment: I have applied this to the header I will update my question and show you what is now happening...

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that it goes _under_ the earlier code you posted. Either that or slap that piece of code in the header for your admin content. It was meant to replace your current foreach

Comment: Hey in my updated question that is where I have placed it in the header of the admin section but I get those errors?

Comment: It was me being thick, I changed it form admin to Admin and now works! Thank you :)